# Borsuk's antipodal theorem and its generalizations and applications: a survey by H. Steinlein

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Is it possible to find the following article?

I want to read this article.

Steinlein, H. (1985). "Borsuk's antipodal theorem and its generalizations and applications: a survey. Méthodes topologiques en analyse non linéaire". Sém. Math. Supér. Montréal, Sém. Sci. OTAN (NATO Adv. Study Inst.). 95: 166–235.

Comment: Do you have access to a university library? They could maybe get it for you via interlibrary loan.

Comment: Gerry Myerson. I have access to a university library, but i don't think i can get it. I wonder if I can get it as online

Comment: Have you tried contacting Prof. Steinlein directly (https://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~steinl/)? He'll be happy to help if he can.

Comment: Mehmet, is your e-mail at Çukurova University still active?

Comment: @DanieleTampieri, Yes, it is active.

Comment: @M.G. I contacted him, he will try to do something for me

Answer (score 2):

This answer follows the same lines of an older one on a similar topic: the full reference is

Heinrich Steinlein, "Borsuk’s antipodal theorem and its generalizations and applications: a survey", (English), *Méthodes topologiques en analyse non linéaire*, [Séminaire de mathématiques supérieures](http://www.crm.umontreal.ca/sms/), SMS095, Séminaire Scientifique OTAN (NATO Advanced Study Institute) 95, Les Presses de l'Université de Montréal,  pp. 166-235 (1985), [MR0801938](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0801938), [Zbl 0573.55003](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0573.55003).

The paper has not been digitized by the publisher yet, as one can check from the [Centre de Recherches Mathématiques (CRM) published seminairs web site](http://www.crm.umontreal.ca/pub/Ventes/Catalogue_SMS_Eng.html). However, the [Hathi Trust Digita library has a digital copy of it](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000356996), thought it is only accessible to Partner Libraries or for other reasons ([see here](https://www.hathitrust.org/accessibility) if you can apply). Thus, in order to get a copy of that paper you can

**A.** [Check](https://www.hathitrust.org/accessibility) if you can apply for [a digital copy of the whole proceedings](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000356996) from the Hathi Trust.

**B.** Purchase a copy of the proceedings from the CRM: as it can be seen from the [above list](http://www.crm.umontreal.ca/pub/Ventes/Catalogue_SMS_Eng.html), the whole book is still available and it is cheap (it costs CDN$ 5 + p&p).

**C.** Proceed as in the "good old days" (obviously taking advantage of modern technologies), i.e. ask a librarian near you for a copy of it (which nowadays it would be possibly made as a .pdf scan), possibly by doing the following steps

1. Check for libraries near you holding the proceedings volume: [the Worldcat lists 8 ***pages*** of libraries around the world holding it](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=ti%3AM%C3%A9thodes+topologiques+en+analyse+non+lin%C3%A9aire+au%3AGranas&qt=advanced&dblist=638) (note that each page link provides sublinks to multiple libraries), so I expect this will be a relatively easy task.
2. Chose one library near you which offers the document delivery service:  sometimes this service has a fee (that may be significant for long documents, as in this case) but it is not always so, therefore check also if the library is able to make a free copy for you.
3. Provide them the full reference as stated above, and wait for the copy.